# Find which tables are used by a set of queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with many tables and a set of queries which are going to be used for a particular application. The queries only use a small subset of the tables in the database and it has been decided to create a new database with just the set of tables which are referenced by the set of queries.

Is there a way to list the tables which are used by a set of queries?

The table names in this case are usually enclosed in square brackets so I can get so far by searching on this e.g. using 'Find In Files' in SQL Server management Studio. Is there a better way, perhaps using the fact that table names are usually preceded by the word 'FROM' or 'JOIN' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these queries are stored procedures, you can right click on them in SSMS and select View Dependencies.

[image: View Dependencies]

Once selected, the Object Dependencies dialog will show, and you will want to toggle the radio button to "Objects on which [Stored procedure Name] depends.

Another option is to generate an estimated query plan, and parse the XML that it generates.

Comment: Unfortunately they're just queries not integrated with the database, but the answer is still very useful and works well for my views as well as stored procedures.

Comment: I'm glad that this is helpful.  See my edit for another approach.